# MaterialCardView backward compatibility

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-library, materialcardview

All MaterialCardView are turning black on pre-Lollipop, specifically API 16 like this:

[image]

I tried to make a style for the card, but it's not working, but it works when I'm using CardView.

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:foreground="@color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/matcard"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:strokeWidth="0.5dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    > ...
 </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Is there a way to fix this without rewriting my code?

## Solved

Problem Solved ! 
By Migrating to AndroidX

Comment: If you have solved your question then you should answer it and select your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Gonzalo oh didn't know that thanks . Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By Migrating to AndroidX & add the new Material Library to gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```